# Laravel & Paypal PHP SDK: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-4

I am trying to do paypal payment using [Paypal PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) for Laravel 4. But when I submit the payment form I get the following error: `Exception: Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl` on a completely white page!

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS! If you have any clue on how to fix this I will be very thankful!

Thank you!

Comment: The message is pretty clear https isn't enabled in your libcurl, to be sure you can look it up in phpinfo(); How to fix it? Enable it.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is useless. I already know that, and I have already checked phpinfo(); but I CANNOT FIND libcurl there! Any other pretty clear answers you'd like to add? And why is the vote down?!

Comment: Once you open up phpinfo page you should see "CURL" somewhere. Under that, you'll see the SSL row. That said, this error can show up when the error has nothing to do with https support. For instance if you submit a url with a whitespace before the 'https' the same error would show.